# android release app bundle build missing native lib .so files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, android-bundle

**case**

I have an app

when i work with it in debug mode everything is ok !

but when i try to build apk bundle for release and try to install app through play store
the is missing the .so files
i reverse- engineered the apk and couldn't find a single .so file or any lib folder

but when i analyse the bundle using play console and android studio it contains all the abi folders with respective .so files

this is my app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 38
        versionName "3.0.8"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
        //render script
        renderscriptTargetApi 28
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
        exclude "lib/mips/libRSSupport.so"
        exclude "lib/mips/librsjni.so"

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    //custom modules here
    //libs and jars
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //other dependencies
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

here are the some images

[image: android studio apk analysis]

i could't screenshot whole page but it had all the possible abis

[image: play console app bundle exploere]

**error**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.test-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libnative-lib.so"
```

**what all i have tried**

i have tried putting ndkFilters, splits, abis, disabling progaurd, etc. in gradle file

but no luck

**i think**

play console is failing to distribute the lib to respective abis

**request**

anyone got any clue of it please tell me **`_/\_`**

thank you

Comment: Have you looked over this? https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use abifFilters to remove the obsolete ABIs from your bundle. You don't need `armeabi` or `mips`.

Maybe, you tried to install an **armeabi** split on a device. The problem with this is that an **armeabi** split does exist (it contains libraries from some dependencies), but the newer NDK did not build this variant of `libnative-lib.so`.

Comment: but thats not what i want

Comment: and if you look at the android studio analysis it doesn't have any content in it folders are generated with no files in it. so its not a problem

Comment: The list that you posted above features armeabi xhdpi bundle which, on the face of it, does not include `libnative-lib.so`, but may include some 3rd party native libraries from the packages that your app depends on, e.g. Crashlytics

Comment: thank you, i haven't tried what you are saying but i can visualize what you are saying. it might solve the problem. but what if there are devices running on those abis. please also tell me what all abis i must target and what i must exclude.

Comment: i also doubt your argument because it was a bundle and the device i tested on runs on arm64-b8a so there is no question of those redundant abi code coming to the apk. and when i cracked the app there was no lib folder or any kind of so file

Comment: You see the device is looking for `/data/app/com.test-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi/libnative-lib.so`. Yes it is pretty strange, arm64 is supposed to take precedence. Which device is this?

Comment: The latest release of NDK does not support MIPS and does not support the (old) armeabi. You should be prepared to support armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a.

Comment: well, it makes sense now. but please tell me all the supported abis and no supported abis for the last time

Comment: I don't see how this solves the issue of native libraries not being installed?

Comment: @3c71 the issue here was not that native libraries were not installed, but that the system chose (for a reason unknown) to look for the native libraries in a wrong ABI folder. Maybe, the [TS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8766958/example) tried to install an **armeabi** split on a device. The problem with this is that an **armeabi** split did exist, but the newer NDK did not build this variant of `libnative-lib.so`.

Answer (score 8):

Add the following to `gradle.properties`, it should help:

```
android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs = false
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this does, and why it should fix the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
```

Comment: Please add some explanation so other can understand !

Comment: It won't help as the generated bundle already contains all .so files. The issue arises when installing the bundle. Android Studio or Play Store don't install any lib!

Answer (score 0):

If the above solutions are invalid, you can try to build once with the debug mode package of the dependent library, and then replace it with the release mode package. After a lot of solutions, I found that this method works, maybe it is related to the compiler cache.